# Dreamhost new formmail not working

Tags: forms, email, dreamhost

Dreamhost recently switched over to a new type of mail called formspree instead of their previous formmail. I have followed their instructions online (https://formspree.io/) and can't get it working. I tried deleting some elements and moving some around but, still cant figure it out. Note: I have changed my email for this post only. In my original code I have double checked that it is the correct email. I am using a gmail address, not sure if that matters.

```
<section class="form">
    <form action="https://formspree.io/myemail@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="myemail@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Mail from ME">
    Name
    <input type="text" name="realname" class="form-control">
    E-mail
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
     Questions/Comments
    <textarea name="comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.mywebsite.com">
    </form>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The name attribute at the bottom needs to be name="_next" instead of name="redirect" inorder for the form to work and me to receive mail in my inbox.

```
<section class="form">
    <form action="//formspree.io/myemail@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="myemail@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Mail from ME">
    Name
    <input type="text" name="realname" class="form-control">
    E-mail
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
     Questions/Comments
    <textarea name="comments" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://www.mywebsite.com">
    </form>
```